# Failed to connect to xxxxx.com port 8280: Connection refused"

Tags: php, curl, connection, port, connection-refused

Here I have tried to get curl request and it works on some servers and did not work in some servers, but it works in local host.
when I print the error msg it says

**"Failed to connect to api.lankagate.gov.lk port 8280: Connection refused".**

Here is the my function:

```
function get_on_going_vehicle_number() {
$vehicle_category = 1;

    $xml_data = '<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:v1="http://schemas.conversesolutions.com/xsd/dmticta/v1">

 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
 <v1:GetOnGoingVehicleNo>
 <v1:vehicleCategory>' . $vehicle_category . '</v1:vehicleCategory>
 </v1:GetOnGoingVehicleNo>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';
$URL = "http://api.lankagate.gov.lk:8280/GetOnGoingVehicleNoDMT/1.0";

    $ch = curl_init($URL);


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: text/xml',
        'Authorization: Bearer 7655a410-d019-3f09-b214-08c40e737af0'
    ));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT,8280);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml_data");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_error($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
    echo $error_msg;

     }

    return $output;
    curl_close($ch);

}
```

we try to telnet:

```
working server: > telnet api.lankagate.gov.lk 8280 Trying 43.224.126.66...
Connected to api.lankagate.gov.lk.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host. Non working server: 
user@dwp-s01:~$ telnet api.lankagate.gov.lk 8280
```

Not working server:

```
Trying 192.168.12.117... 
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused 
user@dwp-s01:~$
```

It'tries to different Ip : 192.168.12.117
Please give me a solution

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple issues here.

1. api.lankagate.gov.lk has firewall enabled.
2. Port 8280 is not free.

I guess you can't disable the firewall on api.lankagate.gov.lk. So, please try some other port.

Comment: But it works for local host and in some other servers. what would be the issue for not working in any servers ?

Comment: http://api.lankagate.gov.lk:8280/GetOnGoingVehicleNoDMT/1.0

Does this work from other servers?

Comment: Yes, I tried this from localhost and 2 other servers it works. one is SSL enabled.

Comment: is there any solution

Answer (score 0):

`192.168.12.117` seems local network.

So, you might have pointed this ip in your host file and have to remove that

Example:

`c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` or `/etc/hosts`

`192.168.12.117 api.lankagate.gov.lk`

Or your network router or proxy (192.168.12.117) blocking you to connect that.

Comment: I changed the host file as you told and still it say's

Comment: Sorry. i did't ask you to change host file like that. If host file have entry like that, please remove it. 
and try `ping api.lankagate.gov.lk` get the ip address